# Lenovo touchscreen on C440

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen

I have a Lenovo C440 all-in-one PC. I just installed Ubuntu on it and have everything setup and working pefectly. The only thing that never worked is the touchscreen. I have ready many different threads and have not found an any solutions.

I have upgraded already to the latest possible kernel and nothing. Af first, when I touched the screen it seemed to just lost focus of the mouse but the touchscreen still didnt function until I played with the mouse for a bit to get it back. Now when I updated to the latest kernel it just seems dead and nothing happenes when I touch the screen.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpfull! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar problem on my lenovo ideapad laptop. 
The touchscreen worked before (kernel 3.11), but after updating the kernel, when touching the touchscreen seem to invoke a 'click and hold' mousebutton effect (mouse also dissapeared) and only for the first time touching the screen. A second attempt touching didn't register anything.

But my touchscreen started working again with the latest kernel 3.17rc4. Maybe it will work for you.